# How do I send an image to the server computer and download it?

Tags: python, sockets

I want to send a screenshot that I took on another computer and send it to mine, the host. I want to do this using sockets. How do I do it? I have this:

```
if command == "screenshot":
    s.send("Command received.".encode())
    screensaveshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screensaveshot.save('screenshot.png')
    imgcounter = 1
    basename = "screenshot.png"
    data = s.recv(4096)
    txt = str(data)
    myfile = open(basename % imgcounter, 'wb')
    myfile.write(data)
    data = s.recv(40960000)
    myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tqdm for your purpose.
Have a look at this site https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/send-receive-files-using-sockets-python 
And if you want to send files to other computers you can use ngrok as a server provider by replacing ngrok's address in your socket connection.